# Match NA's in switch() loop

Tags: r

I want to run switch loop and be able to match `NA`, for example:

```
    switch(var, match1 = do something, match3 = do something)
```

How can do it if `var` is `NA` like so:

```
    switch(var, match1 = do something, match3 = do something, NA = do something)
```

I've also tried `is.na()` instead of `NA` and it didn't work.

Comment: Try ` `NA` ` instead

Comment: It works with single quotes, thanks!

Comment: @konvas You should make that an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this situation, NA has to be escaped using backticks (or quotes)

```
switch(var, match1 = do something, `NA` = do something)
```

One thing to note is that you cannot `switch` NA values directly. For example

```
switch(NA, `NA` = 1)
```

does not work, and you should use e.g.

```
switch(as.character(NA), `NA` = 1)
# [1] 1
```

instead. It is probably better to use `var[is.na(var)] <- ...`