# Is it possible to distinguish between NA_character_ and "NA" in `switch`?

Tags: r, switch-statement, na

In [Match NA's in switch() loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30481699/match-nas-in-switch-loop), the answerer showed that using `` `NA` `` in `switch` would match missing values. However, `"NA"` also matches. I have a character vector which contains both the string `"NA"` as well as missing values `NA`. I'm passing elements of this vector one-by-one to `switch`, but cannot distinguish between the two

```
for (k in c(NA, "NA")) {
  cat(switch(k, "NA_character_" = "C", "NA" = "B", `NA` = "A"))
}

#> BB

for (k in c(NA, "NA")) {
  cat(switch(k, "NA_character_" = "C", `NA` = "A", "NA" = "B"))
}

#> AA
```

I know I could use `if (is.na(k))` to distinguish them, but the purpose of using `switch` was to limit nested of `if ... else` statements, so I would rather use `switch` alone if it is simply a matter of choosing the right name in the list of alternatives. I note that the help file says (with my emphasis):

> If EXPR evaluates to a character string then that string is matched *(exactly)* to the names of the elements in ...

so I wonder if there is a particular meaning of "exactly equal to `NA_character_`" applicable here.

Comment: Sorry it's unclear; maybe the `"NA"` in the title should be `""NA""`. What I mean in both is: is it possible to distinguish between missing values in character vectors and a literal `"NA"`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can create a function to distinguish between the three cases

```
f1 <- function(val){      
   switch(deparse(val),
      "NA_character_" = "C", 
       "NA" = "B", 
      '"NA"' = "A") 
 }

f1(NA)
[1] "B"
f1(NA_character_)
#[1] "C"
f1("NA")   
#[1] "A"
```

---

Using the OP's loop

```
for(k in c(NA, "NA")) cat(f1(k), "\n")
#C
#A
```

In this case, `NA` is regarded as `NA_character_` because it is a character vector.  If we need to use as `NA`, then keep it in a `list`

```
for(k in list(NA, "NA")) cat(f1(k), "\n")
#B 
#A
```

Comment: Thanks! Use `deparse`. I think you should have kept a code chunk from one of your earlier edits: the solution for me was simply to change `switch(k, ...)` to `switch(deparse(k), ...)` and nest quotes for the `"NA"` literal.

Comment: @Hugh thanks, I updated that object.  Instead it is compact to have it inside `switch`.  Updated